# Loop for exporting records from a shapefile and zip each record

Tags: python, arcpy, shapefile, for-loop, zip

I'm trying to build a shapefile for each record in my original shapefile, buffer it and then zip them (i.e. the record and its buffer). I have updated a scripts based on early script published on this link ([Loop for exporting shapefiles from an existing shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/loop-for-exporting-shapefiles-from-an-existing-shapefile)).
The script works for separating each record and buffering but the zipping part is returning an error.
Any suggestion on how to fix the script?

Here is the code :

```
# Import libraries
import arcpy, os
from zipfile import ZipFile

# working file and output locations
input_fc = r'..\path\PWS_2021.shp'

# workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Temp\Queries\Requests'

# Set overwrite option
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Make a Feature Layer for the original shapefile
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_fc, "lyr_MyOriginalLayer")

# Create an empty list to hold the FID numbers
myFIDNumbers = []

# First, loop through the original layer and get all the FID numbers. New_Ref
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lyr_MyOriginalLayer", ["FID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myFIDNumbers.append(row[0])
#print(myFIDNumbers)


# Then create a layer for each FID and export it out
for FID in myFIDNumbers:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("lyr_MyOriginalLayer", "lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "\"FID\" = {0}".format(FID))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "PWS_2021_{0}.shp".format(FID))
    arcpy.analysis.Buffer("lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.shp".format(FID), "4 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND")
    with ZipFile("PWS_2021_{0}.zip".format(FID), "w") as zipObj:
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.shp".format(FID))
    #print("Created ShapefileName_{0}.shp".format(FID))
```

Comment: What is the error message? I think it would be easier to [split by attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm), loop and buffer each then zip

Comment: Hi@BERA, The received error was FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'PWS_2021_Buff4m_0.shp_ . I agree with you that split could be an easier option but again the problem of the zipping would be the same.

Comment: update line zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}".format(FID)) to zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}.shp".format(FID)) you forgot the .shp, your code works and does what it asks but it will only zip up the .shp component of both your files

Answer (score 1):

I have altered your code below to zip the required shapefile extensions

```
# Import libraries
import arcpy, os
from zipfile import ZipFile

# working file and output locations
input_fc = r'..\path\PWS_2021.shp'

out_fldr = r'C:\Temp\Queries\Requests'

# workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = out_fldr

# Set overwrite option
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Make a Feature Layer for the original shapefile
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_fc, "lyr_MyOriginalLayer")

# Create an empty list to hold the FID numbers
myFIDNumbers = []

# First, loop through the original layer and get all the FID numbers. New_Ref
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lyr_MyOriginalLayer", ["FID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myFIDNumbers.append(row[0])
#print(myFIDNumbers)


# Then create a layer for each FID and export it out
for FID in myFIDNumbers:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("lyr_MyOriginalLayer", "lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "\"FID\" = {0}".format(FID))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "PWS_2021_{0}.shp".format(FID))
    arcpy.analysis.Buffer("lyr_MyIndividualLayer{0}".format(FID), "PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.shp".format(FID), "4 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND")
    with ZipFile("PWS_2021_{0}.zip".format(FID), "w") as zipObj:
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}.shp".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}.dbf".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}.shx".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_{0}.prj".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.shp".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.dbf".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.shx".format(FID))
        zipObj.write("PWS_2021_Buff4m_{0}.prj".format(FID))
    #print("Created ShapefileName_{0}.shp".format(FID))
```